# Python reverting bigrams and trigrams

Tags: python, trigram

I have a list of bigrams and trigrams:

```
string = 'do not be sad'

a_list: = ['do', 'not', 'do not', 'be', 'not be', 'do not be', 'sad', 'be sad', 'not be sad']
```

I was wondering if there is a function to reverse the bigram and trigram in `a_list`?  I know I could join all the strings and remove duplicates, but that loses the structure of the sentence.  I'm looking if someone has any tips so that the `a_list` can be reverted back to its original string.

Desired output would be:

```
b_list = ['do not be sad']
```

Comment: What would the desired output be?

Comment: I don't follow the logic that you use to reach `b_list` from `a_list`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You could use a *De Bruijn graph*...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string = 'do not be sad'
string = string.split()

a_list = ['do', 'not', 'do not', 'be', 'not be', 'do not be', 'sad', 'be sad', 'not be sad']

new = []

for a in string:
    for b in a_list:
        if a == b:
            new.append(b)

print([' '.join(new)])
```

Output

```
['do not be sad']
```

and we can make it into a nice one-liner

```
print([' '.join([b for a in string for b in a_list if a == b])])
```

EDIT: IN response to zondo's comment i decided to edit my answer, moreover i found this problem very interesting

```
a_list = ['do', 'not', 'do not', 'be', 'not be', 'do not be', 'sad', 'be sad', 'not be sad']
a_list = ['This', 'is', 'This is', 'my', 'is my', 'This is my', 'car', 'my car', 'is my car']
a_list = ['i', 'am', 'i am', 'a' , 'am a', 'i am a', 'boy', 'a boy', 'am a boy']

largest = max(a_list, key=len) # get the longest sub word in the list

# loop through and if all words of a sublist don't exist in the largest sub word then join them together
for elem in a_list:
    sp = elem.split()
    if all(i not in largest for i in sp):
        if a_list.index(elem) < a_list.index(largest):
            print([elem + ' ' + largest])
        else:
            print([largest + ' ' + elem])
```

i also created several test cases to test my solution, and they all passed

Comment: 1. This doesn't work; `a` will be defined as each *letter* of the string, not each word.  2. If he wanted that, he could simply say `new = [string]`

Comment: also, if `a_list` is edited, it can't follow `string`

Comment: i tested with a modified version of `a_list` and it comes out correct `a_list = ['be', 'do', 'never', 'do not', 'not be', 'not to be', 'something', 'do not be', 'sad', 'be sad', 'not', 'not be sad']
`

Comment: @zondo, you are incorrect. `string` is re-defined as a list of words here: `string = string.split()`, so `a` will, in fact, be  each word.

Comment: I'm sorry; I didn't notice.  I don't think `string` is an appropriate name for a list of strings, though.  My second point is still valid.

Comment: i've edited my current answer, it works even when the list is not sorted too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
a_sentence = [" ".join(word for word in a_list if len(word.split()) == 1)]
print(a_sentence)

# Output: ['do not be sad']
```

Comment: This works because `a_list` is sorted. I think however that the OP wants an algorithm to repair the structure even if the list of *n*-grams is shuffled.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, yes this is what i want.

Comment: Well, I'll leave my answer there just in case it helps someone who, like me, misunderstood the question.

Comment: @zondo i'm sorry that 'I know I could join all the strings and remove duplicates, but that loses the structure of the sentence.' was not clear